# Running Angular2 In Subdirectory

Tags: angular, systemjs

I have an app which runs fine under localhost.

I tried to put it out on an IIS server today as a child application. So the new path would be localhost/SubDir.

System.js pukes everywhere trying to load modules now. I set the basePath and played with the path/map config variables for a few hours but couldn't land on the magic settings.

Does anyone have ideas what I'd want to tweak, or anything that would help with debugging?

Chrome Console
[image]

Chrome Network
[image]

Index HTML

```html
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="~/node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

    <link href="~/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <link href="~/assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <script>
      System.config({
          packages: { 'app': { defaultExtension: 'js' } },
          baseURL: '/MedicheckAngular/',
          paths: {
              //'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/ts/*.js'
          }
      });

      System.import('app/app');
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
</body>
</html>
```

And the App entry point

```js
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {RouteConfig, RouteParams, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, APP_BASE_HREF, ROUTER_BINDINGS, LocationStrategy, PathLocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {AppLayout} from './components/app-layout/app-layout';


bootstrap(AppLayout, [
    ROUTER_BINDINGS,
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue:'/'}),
    provide(LocationStrategy, { useClass: HashLocationStrategy })
]);
```

App Folder Structure

[image]

Answer (score 19):

To host in a sub directory with apache, you can just do this:

Build command similar to this:
ng build --base-href /myapp/

.htaccess file would look like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myapp/
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html [L,QSA]
```

Comment: In my case,  Options +FollowSymLinks causes a serve error. Your solution works by removing that line of code. Thank you

Answer (score 11):

When you're deploying to a non-root path within a domain, you'll need to manually update the following:

```html
<base href="/">
```

to:

```html
<base href="/MedicheckAngular/">
```

in your `dist/index.html`, or make changes as follows:

1. Change `baseUrl: '/MedicheckAngular/'` in `webpack.common.js`.
2. Add `/MedicheckAngular/` to the links in `index.html`.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't know the subdirectory upfront, you can use a dot as path at `/src/index.html` file like this:

```
<base href=".">
```

Then just build with command: `ng build --prod`. Then get the output from inside of `/dist` directory as usual.

Now your app can be placed in any web dir or even works from the filesystem (if no restricted API is used).

Comment: Works for Angular 8. But images are not loading, the src='../assets/images' is 404

Comment: Not sure about previous comment, but this is probably what the devs actually want. I can't think of a reason why any static asset shouldn't be relative.

Answer (score 4):

try to remove the baseURL from the config of systemjs and add the
    `<base href="MedicheckAngular/" />`
to your head part in the HTML DOM.

I had my Angular2 App in the subfolders "modules/angular" from the root.
`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hallo</title>
    <base href="modules/angular/">
</head>
<body>
   <myapp>loading...</myapp>

   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js"></script>
   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js"></script>
   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js">   </script>
   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
   <script src="/modules/angular/node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script>
    System.config({
        packages: {
            "apps": {
                format: 'register',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
    System.import('apps/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Comment: I tried this but now my url always have the sub folder on it. This does not sound right to me. I need to define the base href as subfolder, but still keep my routing clean without this. Do you think this can be done?

Answer (score 3):

I struggled for a while to do something similar.
I have a wordpress running on an apache server.
For SEO reason we wanted the angular app to be hosted on a sub-folder, in the way phpmyadmin is hosted.

1. What I did is to create a subfolder in /apps/my-app-hosting-folder
2. Create an alias to this folder : /my-alias => /apps/my-app-hosting-folder
3. Change the base ref from base href="/" to base href=""

This worked.

The other things I tried didn't give me satisfaction for the following reasons :

- set base ref to the alias : I would have needed to manually fix
  links through the app and with some weird configuration I ended up
  with something like www.exemple.com/my-alias/my-alias/index; something went wrong between the alias and the base ref.
- leaving "/" broked some inner link by adding some weird "/" so I had broken
  url like : www.exemple.com/my-alias/node//blabla; I think it tries to work with the root folder of the server.

Hope it will help the futur readers.

Comment: I had my angular(4) app/dist directory sym-linked (steps 1,2). Changing __base href=""__ fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I put a ~ on the "base href"

```
<!-- Angular2 Code -->
<base href="~/">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
<script src="~/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
<script src="~/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="~/systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
</script>
<!-- Angular2 Code -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what worked for us:

1. Make the base ref point to the subdirectory containing the angular project. This will ensure that all the node_module dependencies are found, etc.
2. Configure the  PathLocationStrategy with a different  APP_BASE_HREF
   so that html5 mode still works for the actual angular app.

   bootstrap(AppComponent,
    [.....
     bind(APP_BASE_HREF).toValue("/yardmap/planning")

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/APP_BASE_HREF-let.html

ref: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Answer (score 1):

Not need to do more , just change one line after the build project in index.html

```
<base href="/">
```

to

```
<base href="/sub directory_name/">
```

If you want to access route in sub-directory more detail here https://angular.io/guide/deployment#production-servers

Answer (score 0):

I think that you've miss a subfolder.

What you've put in your 'index.html' file, means that files to load are located in your home directory.

```
/home/<your_directory>/[...] <- You try to load files from there.
```

I think that your server structure is more like that.

```
/home/<your_directory>/***<app_folder>***/[...] <- I think your files are located here.
```

If you have a console access to your server , try to locate your application folder, with ***pwd*** for example and then replace in your 'index.html' '***~/***' in your ***src*** tags with the returned path and it will work as expected.

Comment: I don't know if I follow what you're suggesting. All the <script> includes from the index.cshtml are pulling in fine with the ~/ paths. Systemjs is having troubles finding the modules though

Comment: Could you provide a structure of your working folder ?

Comment: Sure, I've added a screenshot of the app layout to the question.

Comment: I think that the problem is due to the '~' because it means that your file are located under your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

The full configuration for running Angular app in subdirectory.

Assuming "ng-app/" as the alias path.
For example `http://www.example.com/ng-app/`

> Apache config

```
Alias /ng-app  /<Directory path of index.html>/
Alias /assets /<Directory path of index.html>/assets/
<Directory /<Directory path of index.html>>
    DirectoryIndex index.html

    Require all granted
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
</Directory>
```

> Set baseUrl in index.html

```
<base href="/ng-app/">
```

Suppose the angular-app doesn't work on reload, Add the `LocationStrategy` provider in `app.module.ts`

```
import {LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, in my case what resolved was:

1 - Tip from @SaschaA:

```
<base href=".">
```

2 - Reference the files in "./", example:

```
<link href="./assets/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="./main.a5555dc5a3ce5f94.js" type="module"></script>
```

3 - Disable AdBlock
[image]

Maybe only numbers 2 and 3 will solve it, but that's all I did.
Work's for me!