# Nginx routing to multiple locations with multiple roots in angular ssr build

Tags: angular, nginx

I have my website running and hosted on the server. Let's say my website is `http://example.com`. It built in angular and I built and deployed the dist folder which contains the code on the server, let's say, at `/opt/example_web/dist/browser`. Now when I hit the site, it redirects and loads fine.

I have another two builds (can say) running on the same server, one `http://example.com/api` which is build on `Node.js` and another angular based `http://example.com/admin`. API works fine but the problem is coming up with admin. The home page loads but it isn't able to find the styles and javascript files which are located at `/opt/example_admin/dist/browser`. Error it displays in console is -

```
2019/01/13 10:04:57 [error] 5474#5474: *6 open() "/opt/example_web/dist/browser/admin/styles.3397081055411503ca7a.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.82.102.67, server: edupeeth.com, request: "GET /admin/styles.3397081055411503ca7a.css HTTP/1.1", host: "edupeeth.com", referrer: "https://edupeeth.com/admin"
2019/01/13 10:04:57 [error] 5474#5474: *6 open() "/opt/example_web/dist/browser/admin/runtime.c65c5993662350a7e065.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.82.102.67, server: edupeeth.com, request: "GET /admin/runtime.c65c5993662350a7e065.js HTTP/1.1", host: "edupeeth.com", referrer: "https://edupeeth.com/admin"
2019/01/13 10:04:57 [error] 5474#5474: *6 open() "/opt/example_web/dist/browser/admin/polyfills.0e3ee22c9a47318954a0.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.82.102.67, server: edupeeth.com, request: "GET /admin/polyfills.0e3ee22c9a47318954a0.js HTTP/1.1", host: "edupeeth.com", referrer: "https://edupeeth.com/admin"
2019/01/13 10:04:57 [error] 5474#5474: *8 open() "/opt/example_web/dist/browser/admin/main.0008150f761fd2143e37.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 103.82.102.67, server: edupeeth.com, request: "GET /admin/main.0008150f761fd2143e37.js HTTP/1.1", host: "edupeeth.com", referrer: "https://edupeeth.com/admin"
```

I think I am doing something wrong in nginx config. I am copying below my configuration for nginx. Please suggest the mistake I am doing here.

```
upstream ssr_edu_web {
    server 127.0.0.1:4200;
}

upstream ssr_edu_admin {
    server 127.0.0.1:8081;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name example.com www.example.com; # <--- Change this part

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
      ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    root /opt/example_web/dist/browser; # <-- Notice where we're point to    

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri @backend; # <--- This looks for requests (statics i.e js/css/fonts)
                                      # in /ssr/dist/browser folder. If nothing found, calls @backend
    }

    location @backend {
        # NOTE THERE IS NO TRAILING SLASH AT THE END. NO TRAILING SLASH. NO SLASH. NO!
        proxy_pass http://ssr_edu_web; # <--- THIS DOES NOT HAVE A TRAILING '/'
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

      location /api {
         proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/api;
         proxy_redirect    off;
         proxy_set_header  Host            $host;
         proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
         proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       }

    location /admin {
        alias /opt/example_admin/dist/browser;
        proxy_pass http://ssr_edu_admin; # <--- THIS DOES NOT HAVE A TRAILING '/'        
       }       

}

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name example.com;
      return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri?;
  }
```

Following is `index.html` -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Admin</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.png">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/admin/styles.3397081055411503ca7a.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/runtime.c65c5993662350a7e065.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/polyfills.0e3ee22c9a47318954a0.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/admin/main.0008150f761fd2143e37.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

If I do a curl after logging in to the server where I hosted my website, I am able to do so on `http://127.0.0.1:8081`.

Comment: Did you try Ctrl + F5? Maybe it loads index.html using the cache so it refers to old hashes in JS files

Comment: Where exactly? I tried incognito if you mean at the client side.

Comment: I mean in the browser, indeed if you tried incognito it's the same

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will help, but can you try to split your `/admin` location block in two?

```
    location /admin {
        alias /opt/example_admin/dist/browser;
        try_files $uri @admin;
    }
    location @admin {
        proxy_pass http://ssr_edu_admin; # <--- THIS DOES NOT HAVE A TRAILING '/'        
    }
```

Also take a look at nginx `error.log`, it can contain information about paths where nginx looking for your .js and .css files.

Comment: Sure @Ivan, I will try it out. But what does `@admin` would mean here. I mean never saw something like that earlier. Will update you in a while. Thanks.

Comment: No luck :(. It isn't going to admin root but `example.com` root. Not sure what the heck is it. So, isn't it possible to host two code bases `example.com` and `example.com/admin` and both are having different UI and codebase and running separately. I need to redirect from `example.com` to `example.com/admin`.

Comment: `@admin` is just another named location, like `@backend` location already present in your current config. It will process any request to `/admin` that is not corresponding to an existing file.

Comment: The error is same. `/opt/example_web/dist/browser/polyfills.0e3ee22c9a47318954a0.js failed (2: No such file or directory)`. Its just not going to the right root.

Comment: Hope I am not trying to do something which is not allowed? I mean redirecting from one site to another under same domain of course?

Comment: Redirecting is quite tricky with nginx, but of course you can do any internal redirects under the same domain, unless I don't understand what do you want to redirect and where. What URLs for .css/.js files your admin app generates? From your question I assumed that assets files are requested from `/admin` folder like `https://example.com/admin/runtime.c65c5993662350a7e065.js`, but error from your last comment shows that they are requested from root, like `https://example.com/polyfills.0e3ee22c9a47318954a0.js`. How these URLs really looks in HTML code?

Comment: There are two roots,  lets say. `/opt/example_web/dist/browser` and `/opt/example_admin/dist/browser`. If I hit `https://example.com`, then the assets files are served from the first root perfectly and everything is in place. Now, I developed an admin web page for the same application and deployed it on port 8081, lets say and all asset files lying at second root above. Now, when I hit `https://example.com/admin`, it serves the index page but still refers the first root and not second for the asset files. That is something I need help with.

Comment: I understand your problem. Do you understand my question? From what your wrote in your question (see console errors you provided) I made a conclusion that asset files are requested from `/admin` folder. Your error log entries shows they are requested from root folder. From what path they are really requested? I don't understand why your console errors shows `https://example.com/admin/...` path. Or did you add an `/admin` part to these errors yourself? I'm not familiar with angular, are these asset files static ones or they are generated dynamically by backend?

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. Updated the latest logs. Please lemme know if missing anything yet. And these are all static files.

Answer (score 0):

please refer to [Running Angular2 In Subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34010970/running-angular2-in-subdirectory)

in your case, changes `<base href="/">` to `<base href="/admin">` and
in your nginx configuration, change to following, included partial answer from @ivan-shatsky:

```
location /admin {
    root /your/admin/app/root/here;
    try_files $uri @admin;
}
location @admin {
    proxy_pass http://ssr_edu_admin; # <--- THIS DOES NOT HAVE A TRAILING '/'        
}
```