# Ionic 4 npm run build --prod not working when hosting on Apache server

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

This is my first project on Ionic 4, I have been working in Ionic 3 till now and I use to make builds for web with the command

```
npm run build --prod
```

But when I am making the build in Ionic 4 project using the same command, it is generating a lot of js and map files, around 400 or more files in the **www** folder

> 0-es5.js , 0-es5.js.map , 0-es2015.js , 0-es2015.js.map   till 77-es5.js....  and then my actual pages

[image]

Now when I upload this on my hosting [Apache server] and run, it is not working and is giving error, it's looking for files outside the folder where I have uploaded, I uploaded it in **domain.com/folder**  but it's looking in **domain.com/**.

See this pic:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not use --prod just use build only. it can help u.

Comment: does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42948125

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `<base/>` in `www/index.html` to

```
<base href="qanda">
```

If base href is like `<base href="/" />` then index.html trying to find assets files like css, js from root of your hosting domain.

Comment: after doing this, i am getting - core.js:9110 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'qanda'

Comment: Can you please this https://sapphireprofits.com/qanda in href?